# metadata in the insight query for QnAMaker logs

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-qna-maker

Please let me know how to include metadata in the insight query for QnAMaker logs
something as this, here the meatadata field comes empty

```py
| where url endswith "generateAnswer"
| project timestamp, id, url, resultCode, duration, performanceBucket
| parse kind = regex url with *"(?i)knowledgebases/"KbId"/generateAnswer"
| join kind= inner (
traces | extend id = operation_ParentId
) on id
| extend question = tostring(customDimensions['traces'])
| extend answer = tostring(customDimensions['Answer'])
| extend score = tostring(customDimensions['Score'])
| extend metadata = tostring(customDimensions['qnaMakerOptions'])
| project answer,['metadata']
```

Comment: It seems you have already opened this discussion on MS Q&A and GitHub, adding references to help other community members. You can refer to [metadata in the insight query for QnAMaker logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/565044/metadata-in-the-insight-query-for-qnamaker-logs.html) and [how to include metadata in the insight query for QnAMaker logs](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/issues/3843)

Answer (score 0):

To help the other community Members posting the suggestion from the GITHUB where the issue is discussed.

If you look within the customEvents table, you can find an event with the name 'QnAMessage' - this is an event that is produced by the underlying QnAMaker service within the Bot Framework SDK, and produces more information beyond the trace event you identified. The corresponding class is Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA.QnAMaker, located within the microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet repo.

With this class, it is possible to supply custom event properties and metrics that can be captured within Application Insights. To do this, the recommendation would be to create a custom dialog that inherits from QnAMakerDialog, and add logic as appropriate to supply any additional telemetry properties and metrics.

There is a sample custom dialog, the [MultiplyDialog](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/experimental/adaptive-runtime-packages/multiply-dialog-package) in the samples repo that shows how to write a custom dialog.

The general approach you would take is to write a custom dialog extending from QnAMakerDialog, probably overriding the protected getQnaMakerClient(...) method to return a custom QnAMaker implementation that includes the metadata you care about in the on QnaResults method. Below is some pseudocode that illustrates the example

```html
class CustomQnAMakerDialog extends QnAMakerDialog {
  async getQnaMakerClient(dialogContext) {
    const client = await super.getQnAMakerClient(dialogContext);

    const onQnaResults = client.onQnaResults.bind(client);
    client.onQnaResults = (qnaResults, turnContext, properties = {}, metrics = {}) => {
      properties = { ...properties, custom: 'property' };
      metrics = { ...metrics, custom: 1.0 };

      return onQnaResults(qnaResults, turnContext, properties, metrics);
    }
  }
}
```

For more information about logging metadata into app insights for qna maker service refer the below git hub link with complete code

[QnaMakerDialog](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/main/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA/Dialogs/QnAMakerDialog.cs) & [QnaMaker](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/main/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA/QnAMaker.cs)

Comment: can you please share the C# code for the above javascript pseudo code shared above